# Finding a control inside another control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink

Since there is no link button in WPF I created a link button using  hyperlink and text block controls.

There are 3 controls:

```
<TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  >                
     <Hyperlink Name="hyplnkIsActiveMarkets"  Click="hyplnkIsActive_Click" Foreground="Blue"  >  
         <TextBlock Name="txtblkIsActiveMarkets" Text="Active"  />     
     </Hyperlink>
 </TextBlock>
 <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">                
     <Hyperlink Name="hyplnkIsActiveBudgets"  Click="hyplnkIsActive_Click" Foreground="Blue"  >  
         <TextBlock Name="txtblkIsActiveBudgets"  Text="Active"  />     
     </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock  Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">                
     <Hyperlink Name="hyplnkIsActivePrograms"  Click="hyplnkIsActive_Click" Foreground="Blue"  >  
         <TextBlock Name="txtblkIsActivePrograms"  Text="Active"  />     
     </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

All the link buttons calls same click method

```
private void hyplnkIsActive_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hyperlink objHyperlink = (Hyperlink)sender;
    TextBlock objTextBlock = new TextBlock();

    if (objHyperlink == hyplnkIsActiveMarkets)
    {
        objTextBlock = txtblkIsActiveMarkets;
    }
    else if (objHyperlink == hyplnkIsActiveBudgets)
    {
        objTextBlock = txtblkIsActiveBudgets;
    }
    else if (objHyperlink == hyplnkIsActivePrograms)
    {
        objTextBlock = txtblkIsActivePrograms;
    }

    if (objTextBlock.Text == "Active")
        ChangeHyperLinkStatus(objHyperlink, objTextBlock, Status.Inactive);
    else ChangeHyperLinkStatus(objHyperlink, objTextBlock, Status.Active);
}
```

In the click method I check for the text block inside the hyper link individually using if condition.

Is there any easier way to do this? That's basically finding control inside a control?

Comment: you could use a for loop and check controls

Comment: This might help you: [WPF ways to find controls @ SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls).

Comment: foreach (Control control in parent.Controls){  } within the brackets do your type checking and or casting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it finally . Thanks to Maheep fa his help

```
 TextBlock objTextBlock = (TextBlock)LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(objHyperlink).Cast<System.Windows.Documents.InlineUIContainer>().FirstOrDefault().Child;
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** you can not use VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(...) to get the parent of your hyperlink as you have mentioned hyperlink is not visual. corrected the answer.

See code below.

```
private void hyplnkIsActive_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hyperlink objHyperlink = (Hyperlink)sender;
    TextBlock objTextBlock  = (TextBlock)LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(objHyperlink)[0]; 
   // This will give logical tree first child of objHyperlink


    if (objTextBlock.Text == "Active")
        ChangeHyperLinkStatus(objHyperlink, objTextBlock, Status.Inactive);
    else 
        ChangeHyperLinkStatus(objHyperlink, objTextBlock, Status.Active);
}
```

See this article about [logical tree on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx#logical_tree)

Comment: I am getting exception "'System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink' is not a Visual or Visual3D."

Comment: I am not finding parent of Hyperlink , i want the child inside Hyperlink. but i am not finding child option .

Comment: Isn't he asking about `TextBlock` that is child of the `Hyperlink`?

Comment: Piotr is right . How can find child . I am not getting any option.

Comment: Yes. Updated the answer for getting the child instead of parent.

Comment: cannot do this it gives error "cannot add indexing to a type Ienumerable"

Comment: Then remove [0] and get first child by iterating the IEnumrable

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going into the wrong direction by relaying your execution logic on `controls` and *not* on `data`.

You can, for example, bind a `ICommand` or `RelayCommand` to the buttons, or just subscribe different events, or define a custom `DataTemplate` where on mouse down the clicked control is assignable to some `ModelView` property.

Doing in way you do, you create tough coupling between UI and your execution logic.
In this case easier use `WindowsForm` then `WPF`.